# All custom dialogs have a background

Tags: android, customdialog

While I was working on my project and close to be finished. I've stumbled on a MEGA problem.
The problem is that all of a sudden, without changing anything in my code / layouts, all my custom dialogs has an overlying image (The background of 3 activities).

I have this problem on 2.x devices, it didn't occurred yet on 3.x.
I do work with different layouts depending on screen size. But I've deleted those layouts so they all use the same layout etc. But still.
I even closed my Eclipse, cleaned the project, rebuild manually, un-installed the apk, re-installed the apk. I tested on 2.2.3, 2.2.1 devices (API 8 & 9) and on 3.2

I'm desperate at the moment. So please, does anyone has any advice on how / why this is happening?

Here are a few screen shots for comparison.

2.2.3 screen shot with Dialog (buggy):

[image]

3.2 screen shot -- as it should be (works fine):

[image]

Comment: Um, a little more information would be useful. Perhaps an excerpt of the code you have to create the custom dialog. Best guess, without being able to see any code; a background is being set because of a style or a preset value that matches up with your dialog.

Comment: I had a wrong setting in the dialog layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a few 'wrong' parameters in the layout of the dialog.
As I can remember I setted the translucense parameter to true and used a background_color of #00000000 (Where the alpha channel overwrited the translucense). This was causing the bug.

Changing the layout setting of the background to #000000 (plain black) or removing it fixed this.